# Stop a video when change state in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video

#### Code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ 
   console.log ("state is "+$state.current.name);
   if($state.current.name == 'app.search') {
        player.pause();
   }
});
```

#### Issue:

I want to stop the video when state changes in angularjs.I tried the above code, it works when the if condition is true but the problem is that again change to `app.search` state the video is not stop. That is the code is works only once. the code is not working in the second time if the condition is remains true. I don't know how this happens.

Comment: Are you sure with condition??

Comment: yes . i checked it . its true